# How does one calculate the bandwidth of Nginx host by parsing the logs?

Tags: nginx

Nginx's log has the ability to log the `$bytes_sent` and I am trying to figure out if you could simply collect the requests from the last second, sum them up and get the bandwidth per second.

My question is, when nginx logs the bytes sent for a http 200 request, is this really the amount of data that the customer received, or in other words, does this really represent the current bits per second that I would observe on this TCP port (say, 8080) if I used something like iftop?

My goal is to find a way to log the bits per second going out of the Nginx vhost(server block).